# Suspending computer and maintaining internet connection

Tags: networking, suspend

Some computers in this network have allocated LAN IP addresses, although other computers (the visitors) can sometimes steal the allocated IP addresses. Recently, suspended computers are losing their ability to connect.

When I suspend my computer, are all Internet connections disconnected?

Answer (score 4):

A computer that is suspended isn't on the network and isn't visible to the network. One thing that you can do is configure your [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP) server to hand out automatic IP addresses that are outside the range of your static IPs.

For example, suppose that you have assigned static IP addresses between `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.10`. Configure your DHCP server (possibly part of your router) to automatically assign IPs in the range `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.1.254`. This way, you'll never have to worry about collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the since the computer does not reply any more the connections will time out and be closed.